# Рисование кнопки c#

Tags: c#, button, color

Есть такой вопрос:
каким образом можно наследоваться со стандартной кнопки и прорисовать свою?

Например в Windows7 - синие оттенки кнопки, как изменить на зелёные допустим?

Answer (score 2):

В WPF используйте [SystemColors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors.aspx).

Comment: Мне для WindowsForms

Comment: @JPro, во первых, это надо было указать меткой. а во-вторых, что-то мне подсказывает, что гугл по запросу "SystemColors in winforms" выдаст вам много всего интересного.

Comment: @Макс Жуков, Вы наверно меня не правильно поняли

Comment: >Вы наверно меня не правильно поняли

тогда правильно объясните

Comment: http://ssmaker.ru/6027edf3.png

Comment: @JPro вы не телеграмму пишете, не нужно экономить слова. Опишите конкретно, что вы хотите. Эта ваша замечательная картинка - пример стандартной кнопки, чуть растянутой в высоту. Вы хотите стандартную кнопку? Нет ничего проще

Comment: @DreamChild видите синие тона? Как изменить на зелёные например?

Answer (score 1):

**Использовал последний талончик на гадалку

Вы это хотели?

```
namespace proj
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CreateButt();
        }

        public void CreateButt()
        {
            Color slateBlue = Color.FromName("SlateBlue");

            Button butt = new Button();
            butt.Parent = this;
            butt.Top = 12;
            butt.Left = 12;
            butt.Width = 50;
            butt.Height = 25;
            butt.BackColor = slateBlue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://ssmaker.ru/6027edf3.png

Comment: и что вам мешает взять вышеуказанный код и подставить нужный вам цвет?